# XML transformation - XSL template match multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to modify the ets4_import from calimero to match old ETS4 projects and new ones.

Is it possible to modify

```
<xsl:template match="/"  xmlns:b="http://knx.org/xml/project/11">
```

to something like

```
<xsl:template match="/"  xmlns:b="http://knx.org/xml/project/11 or http://knx.org/xml/project/10">
```

The XML file is either starting with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KNX xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" CreatedBy="ETS4" ToolVersion="ETS 4.0.3 (Build 3250)" xmlns="http://knx.org/xml/project/11">
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<KNX xmlns="http://knx.org/xml/project/10" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" CreatedBy="ETS4" ToolVersion="4.0.1387.12605">
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/rWnqVusq) is the complete XSL file.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:b10="http://knx.org/xml/project/10" xmlns:b="http://knx.org/xml/project/11" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="b:KNX/b:Project/b:Installations/b:Installation/b:Topology">
            <datapoints>
            <xsl:for-each select="b:Area/b:Line/b:DeviceInstance/b:ComObjectInstanceRefs/b:ComObjectInstanceRef">
                <xsl:sort select="b:Connectors/b:Send/@GroupAddressRefId"/>
                <xsl:if test="not(preceding::b:Connectors/b:Send/@GroupAddressRefId = current()/b:Connectors/b:Send/@GroupAddressRefId)">
                    <xsl:for-each select="b:Connectors">
                        <xsl:variable name="verz" select="document(concat(substring(../@RefId,0,7),'/',substring-before(../@RefId, '_O'), '.xml'))/b:KNX/b:ManufacturerData/b:Manufacturer/b:ApplicationPrograms/b:ApplicationProgram/b:Static/b:ComObjectTable/b:ComObject[@Id = ../../b:ComObjectRefs/b:ComObjectRef[@Id = current()/../@RefId]/@RefId]" /> 
                        <xsl:variable name="grosse">
```

Is there a possibility to define

```
b: = b: | b10:
```

so that I don't have to change the complete file

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:b10="http://knx.org/xml/project/10" xmlns:b11="http://knx.org/xml/project/11">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="b10:MyElement|b11:Element">
      <!-- Template code... -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

although since you are matching the root element, and you only transform one XML document at a time, I don't quite see the problem, because `/` will match the root element in any case.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but after the template match I have a select="b:KNX/b:Project..." which is not working anymore.
If I have select="b11:KNX/b11:Project..." it is working, but I want to use both versions.

Comment: Then maybe what you need is b10:KNX/b10:Project|b11:KNX/b11:Project, but to be sure, I need a small but complete (non-pseudo) example of your input XML, your expected output, and the result you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2.0 you could first change (or possibly even strip) the namespace of the document and then apply the gigantic template you have.  In XSLT 1.0, you could replace all occurences of `b:XYZ` with `*[local-name()='XYZ']`.